# Gnuplot three .csv-files with different times in same timefmt

Tags: csv, plot, gnuplot

I have 3 .csv-files in same timefmt, but with different times and i want to plot them over each other.

The files are build like this:

```
NO.;Time;ms;" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";" V";"A1234567890";"A1234567890";"AO1234/WLAO12345"
1;2022-11-25 15:43:42;0;+3.344;-0.013;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.002;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
2;2022-11-25 15:43:42;200;+3.344;-0.012;+0.002;+0.001;+0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.002;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
3;2022-11-25 15:43:42;400;+3.345;-0.013;+0.003;+0.001;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.001;+0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
4;2022-11-25 15:43:42;600;+3.344;-0.012;+0.002;+0.001;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;+0.002;+0.001;+0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
5;2022-11-25 15:43:42;800;+3.344;-0.012;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.002;+0.001;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
6;2022-11-25 15:43:43;0;+3.344;-0.012;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
7;2022-11-25 15:43:43;200;+3.344;-0.012;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;-0.002;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
8;2022-11-25 15:43:43;400;+3.344;-0.012;+0.002;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.002;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.000;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
9;2022-11-25 15:43:43;600;+3.345;-0.012;+0.002;+0.000;-0.001;+0.000;-0.002;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;-0.001;-0.001;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
10;2022-11-25 15:43:43;800;+3.344;-0.012;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
11;2022-11-25 15:43:44;0;+3.344;-0.011;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
12;2022-11-25 15:43:44;200;+3.344;-0.011;+0.002;+0.000;-0.001;+0.000;-0.002;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.002;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;-0.002;+0.000;-0.001;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
13;2022-11-25 15:43:44;400;+3.344;-0.011;+0.002;+0.000;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.001;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.002;+0.000;-0.001;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
14;2022-11-25 15:43:44;600;+2.890;-0.011;+0.002;+0.000;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.002;+0.001;+0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
15;2022-11-25 15:43:44;800;+2.878;-0.012;+0.002;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
16;2022-11-25 15:43:45;0;+2.881;-0.013;+0.003;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
17;2022-11-25 15:43:45;200;+2.870;-0.013;+0.002;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
18;2022-11-25 15:43:45;400;+2.869;-0.012;+0.002;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.000;-0.002;+0.001;+0.001;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
19;2022-11-25 15:43:45;600;+2.874;-0.012;+0.003;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.002;-0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.002;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.000;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
20;2022-11-25 15:43:45;800;+2.869;-0.011;+0.003;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.002;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.002;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
21;2022-11-25 15:43:46;0;+2.869;-0.010;+0.002;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
22;2022-11-25 15:43:46;200;+2.870;-0.010;+0.002;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.003;+0.001;+0.000;+0.001;-0.002;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.002;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
23;2022-11-25 15:43:46;400;+2.873;-0.011;+0.003;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;+0.001;+0.000;+0.000;-0.002;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.002;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
24;2022-11-25 15:43:46;600;+2.868;-0.011;+0.002;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.002;+0.000;+0.001;+0.001;-0.002;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.002;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
25;2022-11-25 15:43:46;800;+2.870;-0.010;+0.002;+0.000;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;+0.000;-0.001;+0.002;+0.000;+0.000;+0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.001;-0.001;+0.001;-0.002;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLLL;LLLLLLLLL
...
```

Here I just need the 2nd & 4th column.

And my Code look like:

```
set grid
set datafile separator ";"
set title 'xxx'
set title font ",12"
set ylabel 'U/V' font ",12"
set key box font ",12"
#myformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
#set key at strptime(myformat,"2022-11-24 18:02:55"), 3.005
set xtics time
set xlabel 'time' font ",12"
set yrange [2.4:3.6]
set ytics font ",10"
set y2tics font ",10"
set border 11
set border lw 2
set xtics font ",8"
set tics nomirror
set term wxt size 1200, 460
set xdata time
#set timefmt "%s"
#set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s"
#set timefmt "%tH:%tM:%tS"
#set format x "%M:%S" time
#set xrange ["2022-11-25 15:40:00":"2022-11-26 17:05:00"]
#set xrange ["17:20:00":"18:47:00"]
#set xrange 0:7000
#print strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",s)
#myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
#Normalize(c) = (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(c,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(c,myTimeFmt)-t0)

#plot t=0 'xxx.CSV' using (Normalize(2)):4 every ::43::6849 title "aaa" lt 7 lc 7 with lines, \
#'yyy.CSV' using (Normalize(2)):4 every ::43::6382 title "bbb" lt 7 lc 7 with lines, \
#'zzz.CSV' using (Normalize(2)):4 every ::43::5928 title "ccc" lt 7 lc 7 with lines

plot 'xxx.CSV' using (timecolumn(2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")):4 every ::43::6849 title "aaa" lt 7 lc 7 with lines, \
'yyy.CSV' using (timecolumn(2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")):4 every ::43::6382 title "bbb" lt 7 lc 7 with lines, \
'zzz.CSV' using (timecolumn(2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")):4 every ::43::5928 title "ccc" lt 7 lc 7 with lines
```

I tried many different things, but without the desirable effect.
Does somebody know, what I can do?

I expanded the .csv-file.
And this is my actual code:

```
set grid
set title 'Entladung der Batterie nach verschiedenen Ladungen'
set tics nomirror
set title font ",12"
set ylabel 'U/V' font ",12"
set key box font ",12"
set xtics time
set xlabel 'time' font ",12"
set border 11
set border lw 2
set xtics font ",8"
set term wxt size 1200, 460
myFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set datafile separator ";"
set format x "%tH:%M:%S" #timedate
set yrange[2.5:3.6]

plot 'Entladen1C.CSV' u (t=timecolumn(2,myFmt), $0==0?t01=t:0, t-t01):4 every ::43::6849 lt 7 lc "red" with lines      ti "Entladung nach 1C Ladung", \
     'Entladen0.5C.CSV' u (t=timecolumn(2,myFmt), $0==0?t02=t:0, t-t02):4 every ::43::6382 lt 7 lc "web-green" with lines ti "Entladung nach 0,5C Ladung", \
     'Entladen0.2C.CSV' u (t=timecolumn(2,myFmt), $0==0?t03=t:0, t-t03):4 every ::43::5928 lt 7 lc "blue" with lines      ti "Entladung nach 0,2C Ladung"
```

With this code I get the following plot:

[image: Output from this code]

It looks very good till now.
But when I zoom in now, we can see, that there is an offset from 7 seconds on the green graph.

[image: Zoom]

Thats because I told my measuring-device to record, before the event happened. So I want the graph to begin with 7 seconds on x=0. But so that the time starts again from zero.

Comment: So, you want to plot all 3 files relative to their starting time, correct?

Comment: Yes, this ist correct.

Comment: Or better: THIS plus an offset of +/- max. 60 sec, because I don’t know if the measurements were made at the same distance from the event being measured

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to shift your data by the first time of the corresponding dataset.
You can do this by storing the first time entry, i.e. when row index `$0==0` into the variables `t01,t02,t03` and subtracting these from all other values in the dataset.

The following is not using `set xdata time` but just plots the data as seconds  but formatted on the x-axis as `set format x "%tH:%M" timedate`. Actually, `%tH` is not wrapping at 24 hours. Check `help time_specifiers`.

***Edit:***

- take the milliseconds (here: in column 2) into account. Define a function which adds 1/1000 of the value in column 2 to the time.
- add a constant shift (here of 7 seconds) to one of the data sets.
- use `"%tM:%tS"` for time formatting, especially if you want to display negative times.

**Script:**

```
### shift time by starting time
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
2022-11-25 15:43:00;  0;   1.0
2022-11-25 15:43:17;200;   2.0
2022-11-25 15:44:00;400;   3.0
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
2022-10-09 23:59:07;  0;   4.0
2022-10-09 23:59:37;200;   3.0
2022-10-10 00:00:07;400;   1.0
2022-10-10 00:00:37;800;   2.0
EOD

$Data3 <<EOD
2022-09-30 08:22:00;  0;   3.0
2022-09-30 08:22:14;400;   4.0
2022-09-30 08:23:11;800;   2.0
EOD

myFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set datafile separator ";"
set format x "%tM:%tS" timedate
set xlabel "Minutes:Seconds"
set yrange[0:5]

myTime(col1,col2) = timecolumn(col1,myFmt)+column(col2)/1000
dt1 =  0
dt2 = -7
dt3 =  0

plot $Data1 u (t=myTime(1,2), $0==0?t01=t:0, t-t01+dt1):3 w lp pt 7 lc "red"       ti "Data1", \
     $Data2 u (t=myTime(1,2), $0==0?t02=t:0, t-t02+dt2):3 w lp pt 7 lc "web-green" ti "Data2", \
     $Data3 u (t=myTime(1,2), $0==0?t03=t:0, t-t03+dt3):3 w lp pt 7 lc "blue"      ti "Data3"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, now it worked, Thank you. But unfortunately the measurement starts 7 seconds after the instrument started recording. How I can add an individual fixed offset? I tried many things, but nothing works for me.

Comment: @Pascal so, you data is in order of seconds? This could not be seen from your example data, actually , the two first (and only) lines have the identical timestamp `2022-11-25 15:43:42`. Wait, each measurement as an individual offset, but you are plotting relative times from starting time. So, an offset does not matter or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: I edited my question. the csv-file is now longer and i updated my actual code with output. the current problem is now illustrated.

Comment: @Pascal now, the milliseconds in column 2 are taken into account and one curve is shifted by 7 seconds. I hope this is what you were looking for.